# When is toString() get called implicitly in javascript?

Tags: javascript, tostring

With reference to below code written in Javascript.

```js
let a = {
    value: 2,
    toString: function() {
        return ++this.value;
    }
}
if (a == 3 && a == 4) {
    console.log('Condition is true');
}
```

The output is `"Condition is true"`. Looks like it invokes `toString()` function. But how?

When I replace `"=="` with `"==="`, condition does not evaluates to true and it does not invoke `toString()` function this time?

Can someone explain me in detail what's going under the hood?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: Doesn't print anything for me

Comment: I don't think that would be evaluated to true.

Answer (score 1):

> The output is "Condition is true". Looks like it invokes 'toString()'
>   function.

Everytime you use `==` operator between two variables with different types it is invoked internally `toString` method which will coerce one `member`. Have a look at [type coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

> But how?

You're creating a custom `toString` function for your `a` object that changes what it returns each time it is used such that it satisfies all two conditions.
You can also use `valueOf` method.

> How about `===` operator ?

Otherwise, the `===` operator will **not do** the conversion.

> What means this ?

If you're using `===` operator with two values with different type `===` will simply return **false**.

Comment: `The output is "Condition is true".` Any explanations about it?

Comment: Just for future readers: _"Everytime you use `==` operator between two variables with different types it is invoked internally `toString` method"_ [is not true](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) when, e.g., comparing a number to a string.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `==` it is not a strict comparison so what it does for the condition `a == 3 && a == 4`, is that first it compares `a == 3`. Since, it is not a strict comparison, it will change `a` to string. And since you have `toString()` in `a`, that will increment the value of `a` from 2 to 3 and hence `a == 3` result in `true`. Then, `a == 4` checks the same way and this time the value of `a` is `3` so when it checks for `a == 4` it results in `true` by invoking the `toString()` function of `a`.

```js
let a = {
  value: 2,
  toString: function() {
    return ++this.value;
  }
}
if (a == 3 && a == 4) {
    console.log('Condition is true');
}
```

However, when you use `===`, it works as a strict comparison and the type of LHS should match RHS. Thus, `a` is a object in LHS and there is a number type in RHS, so it results `false` for `a == 3` and hence, `a == 3 && a == 4`

```js
let a = {
  value: 2,
  toString: function() {
    return ++this.value;
  }
}
if (a === 3 && a === 4) {
  console.log('Condition is true');
} else {
  console.log('Condition is false');
}
```

Comment: This makes sense. Better than others.

Comment: @Jai I am happy to let know that you understood at some extent :-)

Answer (score 1):

Happen to notice that `toString` is invoked in interpolated string, executed prioritized than `valueOf`

```
var a = {
    value: 1000,
    toString: () => 'call toString method',
    valueOf: () => 'call valueOf method'
};

console.log(`interpreted value: ${a}`); // interpreted value: call toString method
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mihai's answer, `===` is a strict typechecking equality operator which checks for the type of the operands and the values as well.

In your case, the type of `a` is an object, whereas `3` and `4` are numbers. So the condition doesn't evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

it checks whether object has falsy value or not when you use == thats why you get true from a == 4 and a == 3. Have a look at **type coercion**. It does not coerce variables when comparing them and thats why you cannot get into the block statement

Answer (score 0):

You can find detail information of how '==' and '===' works in javascript from link below:
[Equality comparisons and sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness.)

In this URL refer 'Loose equality using ==' section.

In you case your comparison as a == 3. a is object and 3 is number. So comparison will take place as ToPrimitive(a) == 3. What ToPrimitive(a) do is it attempting to invoke varying sequences of a.toString and a.valueOf methods on A. This is how your toString function is called.

Answer (score 0):

On the surface your question looks like the sheer difference between `==` and `===` operators, but in fact there is bit more to it.

For your first question, since javascript is **not strictly typed language**, there is 2 operators, `==` will try to convert the left operand to right ones type if possible whereas `===` will give false if the types are different with the exception of `NaN`.

A more interesting question is when `toString` method gets called. Normally when you create an object, either by typing an object literal or through a constructor, it will inherit `toString` from the Object, you easily check this:

```
var u = function(){};
var w = {};
u.prototype.toString === Object.prototype.toString //true
w.toString === Object.prototype.toString //true as well
```

Now what you might forget is that there is also a `valueOf` method:

```
u.prototype.valueOf === Object.prototype.valueOf //true
w.valueOf === Object.prototype.valueOf //true as well
```

But what does it do? I points to itself:

```
w.valueOf === w //true
u.prototype.valueOf() === u.prototype //true as well
```

So when an object is given, the first choice is to use the `toString` becuae `valueOf` will result in the object itself. What does `toString` give by default? it can depend on what is there on its prototype chain:

```
w.toString() //"[object Object]"
u.toString() //"function (){}"
u.prototype.toString.call(u) //"[object Function]"
```

So by default the first choice is to use the **nearest `toString`** method of the object. Now to see what happens if we override **BOTH** `valueOf` and `toString`, let me construct this object:

```
 var x = {
    inner:10,
    ledger:[],
    result:[],
    timeout:0,
    toString:function(){
        console.log("String");
        clearTimeout(this.timeout);
        this.timeout = setTimeout((function(){
            this.result = this.ledger;
            this.ledger = []}).bind(this)
        ,0) ;
        this.ledger.push("toString");
        this.ledger.slice(-2);
        return String(this.inner);
    },
    valueOf:function(){
        console.log("Valueof");
        clearTimeout(this.timeout);
        this.timeout = setTimeout((function(){
            this.result = this.ledger;
            this.ledger = []}).bind(this)
        ,0) ;
        this.ledger.push("valueOf");
        this.ledger.slice(-2);
        return this.inner;
    }
}
```

This object will keep a "ledger", an array of `valueOf` or `toString` or both called during type conversion. It will also `console.log`. So,here are some operations that will trigger type conversion just like `==`:

```
 +x //10
//ValueOf

"5" + x //"510"
//ValueOf

x + [] //10
//ValueOf

x + "str"//"10str"
//ValueOf

x.toString() //"10"
//String

String(x) //"10"
//String

x + {u:""} //"10[object Object]"
//valueOf
```

So in many cases if a **non-default valueOf** is found that is used. If the right operand is a string, then the returned value from `valueOf` is converted to string rather than `toString` on the object. To override default behavior you can force call to string by using `toString` or `String(` as shown in the examples. So the priority list goes as:

**Custom valueOf >> custom toString >> default toString >>>> default valueOf**

Comment: Just for future readers: _"`==` will try to convert the left operand to right ones type if possible"_ is true for the example code (where the right operand is a number), [but not in general](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3).